# Find the image path included in a document

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../Images/}}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Android-Touchpad} \qquad \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Android-TapLocked}
\end{document}
```

I need to replace the image `Android-TapLocked` with a new one. The document compiles fine and shows the old image. However, I cannot find it.

**Steps tried**:

1. Run `dir /s` command in Windows command prompt.
2. Use Windows 8.1 search function on the entire drive.
3. Sift through images one by one.

**Setup**:

1. Windows 8.1
2. TexLive 2015
3. Texstudio
4. xelatex

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Since this is not a LaTeX provided image, the image is either in the current folder, or back up one level and then down in the Images folder (`../Images`)

Comment: Searched the entire tree. Is there a log or something as to where the image is being linked from?

Comment: There is a log-file, and it should show you the path of the graphic.

Comment: Found it! thanks @UlrikeFischer. Please post your comment as an answer. Or if the mods want, I'd gladly delete the question.

Comment: Where was it???

Comment: @daleif Somehow it was marked `hidden` in properties. The log file showed the exact path. Pasted the path and opened it in GIMP.

Comment: Sometimes windows is a strange os